# How do I include JSON arrays with other variables in my htaccess file?

Tags: php, json, .htaccess

---

UPDATE:
   I've updated my URL to the following:

scriptIWrote/1111/%5B%7B%93num%94%3A%93NX543%20.c38%202000%94%7D%2C%7B%93num%94%3A%93NX543%20.c38%202000%94%7D%5D.json

Which gives an array like this: ( when I use print_r($_GET['nums']) )

```
[{“num”:“NX543 .c38 2000”},{“num”:“NX543 .c38 2000”}]
```

Which is valid JSON, but does not get decode by the line:

```
$callNums = json_decode($_GET['nums'], true);
```

However, replacing "json_decode" with just "array" actually treats $_GET['nums'] like a string and still doesn't work

---

So I'm attempting to pass a JSON array by URL for an API I'm writing, like so:

```
scriptIWrote/1111/[0000,0000].json
```

and I have my htaccess rule set up like so:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} GET
RewriteRule ^scriptIWrote/([^/]+)/([^/]+)(?=.json) root/scriptIWrote/doThing.php?type=$1&names=$2 [L,QSA]
```

However, when I print out what's contained in the parameters like so:

```
$names = json_decode($_GET['nums'], true);
//array of sheet values
$type = $_GET['type'];


error_log($names[0] . $nums[1]);
error_log($type);
```

$nums[0] and $nums[1] are blank, but $type displays the proper value; I know I'm making a mistake in my htaccess, but I'm not sure what I did wrong...

Comment: begin to `print_r($_GET['names']);` and check if this is what you are expecting

Comment: that shed some light on what's going on, but I'm not there yet :(

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem with `json_decode`. Your `$_GET['name']` should be a string representing  json data. When you are giving this data to `json_decode`, it will evaluate your json string and return an array. check this out : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c1a0c124afeebea760046f3989cdd728896c8d29

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of possible problems.  First `[` and `]` are reserved general delimiters characters in URL's.  If you want to use them they need to be percent encoded.

Second `[frank,bob]` is not valid JSON.  You need double quotes around those values.

I have never heard of anyone passing JSON in the URL.  This seems like an ill-conceived idea.

Comment: hey- thanks for clearing some of that up :) I know it sounds like a bad idea, but I'm just a pawn, I gotta follow orders... Anyways, I URL-encoded the array, but to no avail :/

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out:

URL:

```
scriptIWrote/1111/%5B%22NX543%20.c38%202000%22%2C%22NX543%20.c38%202000%22%5D.json
```

PHP:

```
$nums = json_decode(stripslashes($_GET['nums']), true);
```

Comment: Wow I feel for you. that is one atrocious looking URL and pretty much defeats the purpose of having clean URL's.  Can the data be passed via POST?